# How to detect Cordova / Phonegap app network connection is roaming

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I have not been able to find this in the Phonegap/Cordova docs. Is there a way to tell whether a network connection type is roaming? I want to allow the user of the app to constrain the application to only allow data transfers of a certain type (Data intensive) when on their own network and not roaming.

network = navigator.connection.type only gives you the type of carrier data connection (Or even just CELL on iOS) but nothing about whether the user is roaming.

Many thanks

Comment: It isn't possible on iOS. For android you'll have to create your own plugin for roaming detection

Comment: Data roaming is something that the user has to explicitly enable on iOS via Settings; it's intended to be controlled by the user not the app - [see here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201299)

Comment: I don't want to control roaming. I just want to detect it so that I can offer the user the option of preventing the app from sending and receiving data when they are on roaming data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. In case anybody else comes looking for the answer to this. It seems based on research elsewhere and also what jcesarmobile said, you can't detect this on iOS anyway so that would explain why there is nothing in Cordova for this. While my primary platform for the app is initially Android and it might be possible to create a plugin for that, the ultimate goal is to be multi-platform and there won't be this facility in iOS so for our project we'll drop the requirement.